# call props function with parmeters from child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-props

I want to call function with paramter from child compponent, i pass the function as a props and when i call this function its get to her but the paramter that i pass to the function is undiffend.

how can i call this function and send to her parmetrs?

here is my code:

**perent function:**

```
  async function doSomething(param){
//here i see in debug that param is undiffend
var do = param*2
console.log(do)
}
```

**the call of the child componnet:**

```
<child doSomething ={()=>doSomething()}/>
```

**child:**

```
export default function child(props) {
    const { doSomething} = props;
return (
            <div  onClick={() => doSomething(3)}>
           <button></button>
            </div>
    
)
 }
```

Comment: try this: `<child doSomething={doSomething}/>`

Answer (score 2):

Pass the function as a reference:

```
<Child doSomething={doSomething} />
```

or proxy the args through if you want to keep the anonymous callback function:

```
<child doSomething ={(...args) => doSomething(...args)} />
```

Child invokes the function and passes arguments:

```
export default function Child(props) {
  const { doSomething} = props;
  return (
    <div onClick={() => doSomething(3)}>
      ....
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you do not need to call function when passing into child component
just type like this:

```
<Child doSomething={doSomething}/>
```